# Problems with downloading Texstudio 3.1.1 for Mac

Tags: texstudio

I have earlier succeeded with downloading TexStudio for my Mac, though had to circumvent security notices by the system which warned about unknown developer.

I was now not able to install and open the stable release 3.1.1, from MacUpdate.com. MacTex is installed, and I have Big Sur 11.1.

There is no error message beyond the warning that the program is from an unknown developer, and I do not succeed with circumventing this as I have done during installation of earlier releases of Texstudio.

By using the same procedure afterwards I succeeded with downloading Texmaker, so it seems that the problem is with Texstudio.

What may be wrong?

Comment: What is ther error message when you install and try to launch it?

Comment: @Herb Schulz There is no error message, besides the message that the program is from an unknown developer. I tried to circumvent this, as I did before, and insisted that I wanted to open the program. But it did not open.

Comment: The usual process for this is to try to open it. The failure message has a button to show the app; click that. Then Ctl-Click (or Right-Click) the app and use the Open option. The error message then has an Open button which works. From then on it opens normally. is that what you tried?

Comment: No, the reaction is not usual and there is no error message. I will edit to stress this.

Comment: Go to [link](https://www.texstudio.org) and download version 3.1.2. Hopefully that runs.

Comment: That I already tried.

Comment: @HerbSchulz I contacted Texstudio for advice.

Comment: I found a way to hack it.

Comment: And what was that so others can find out if needed?

Comment: @HerbSchulz Would it be looked upon nicely by Apple if one advices people on how to download software from anywhere? If it is not a big problem, I may write it up as an answer.

Comment: Do you have any news for us? A solution?

Comment: @Mensch It has seemed to me that these things are changing so rapidly that it is of no use to remember, and now I do not remember what I did last time - a month ago - to download TexStudio for Mac, which is not produced by Apple.  So it is a little bit complicated. I do remember that I at one point learned from a video instruction by an Indian, so there are useful things to be found by searching.